# Загрузка данных в HBase

Tags: big-data, apache-spark

Есть много данных. Очень много... Около 6 ТБ (или около 6.5 миллиардов строк в виде обычной плоской таблицы).

Данную информацию хочется увидеть в HBase.

В настоящий момент сорсы есть в `hdfs` в виде AVRO-файлов или уже обработанные в виде HIVE-таблицы.

Если в лоб использовать интеграцию [HIVE-HBASE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration), то на кластере создается порядка 25к MR-тасок, максимально на исполнении при этом около 2к. Все таски валятся по таймауту. (у меня есть предположение, что таскам при таком разбиении не хватает памяти, но я не уверен). Как воркэраунд - разбиваю данные примерно на 10 частей (условие по численному id) и таким образом загружаю их.

Вопрос - есть ли какой-либо подход (инструмент) для того, чтобы грузить сразу из AVRO в HBase минуя Hive по аналогии с приведенной выше ссылкой (то есть, максимально просто / минимально возможным количеством кода)?

PS. Как рабочий вариант я также рассматриваю Spark, но внятных примеров подобной интеграции я не нашел.